# .htaccess RewriteRule with 2 php GET variable

Tags: .htaccess

works fine with 1 GET

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^store/([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?store=$1 [L,QSA]
```

not working when i add another GET

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^store/([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?store=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

    localhost/store.php?store=3&name=abc
    -> localhost/store/3/abc
```

I have a htaccess rewrite rule, it works fine in 1 GET, but i try to add another GET into it and its not working.

Comment: add another GET into it ??

Comment: Where is $2 defined? You only have $1 created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^store/([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?store=$1 [L,QSA]    

RewriteRule ^store/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?store=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

> RewriteRule ^store/([^/.]+)/name/([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?store=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]